# Select all orders with the specified status saved in another table (PDO)

Tags: mysql, select, pdo, left-join, where-clause

At the moment i have all informations of a order in one table, including the order status.

In the future i will have a new table "status" to make a order history.

My tables currently look like this (simplified):

Table "orders":

| id | date | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 2021-08-24 16:47:52 | Surname Lastname |
| 10002 | 2021-08-30 17:32:05 | Nicename Nicelastname |

Table "status":

| id | order_id | statusdate | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10001 | 2021-08-24 16:47:52 | new |
| 2 | 10002 | 2021-08-30 17:32:05 | new |
| 3 | 10001 | 2021-08-26 13:44:11 | pending |
| 4 | 10001 | 2021-09-02 10:01:12 | shipped |

My problem is: At this moment i can select all orders with status "shipped" to list them like that:

`$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status = ?");`

(? is my status, e.g. "shipped")

I know i have to use LEFT JOIN to combine the two tables (correct? or is there a better/easier way?), but i have absolutely no idea how i can select all orders with status X, because the "status" table can have multiple entries per order_id... So the statement must select only the newest entrie!?

Comment: which mysql version?

Comment: We use MySQL 5.7.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iy you have no 1 timestamps with the same date, you can use the first query the second is in case you can have multiple timestampo for the same order

> ```
> CREATE TABLE orders
>     (`id` int, `date` varchar(19), `name` varchar(21))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO orders
>     (`id`, `date`, `name`)
> VALUES
>     (10001, '2021-08-24 16:47:52', 'Surname Lastname'),
>     (10002, '2021-08-30 17:32:05', 'Nicename Nicelastname')
> ;
>
>
> CREATE TABLE status
>     (`id` int, `order_id` int, `statusdate` varchar(19), `status` varchar(7))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO status
>     (`id`, `order_id`, `statusdate`, `status`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 10001, '2021-08-24 16:47:52', 'new'),
>     (2, 10002, '2021-08-30 17:32:05', 'new'),
>     (3, 10001, '2021-08-26 13:44:11', 'pending'),
>     (4, 10001, '2021-09-02 10:01:12', 'shipped')
>     ,
>     (5, 10001, '2021-09-02 10:01:13', 'shipped')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> select o.`id` FROM orders o
> ```
>
> ```
> |    id |
> | ----: |
> | 10001 |
> | 10002 |
> ```

> ```
> select o.`id`,o.`date`, o.`name`,s.`statusdate`
> from orders o join status s on o.`id` = s.order_id
> where s.`status` = "shipped"
> AND s.`statusdate` = (SELECT MAX(`statusdate`) FROM `status` WHERE order_id = o.`id` AND `status` = "shipped")
> order by o.`id` desc
> ```

> ```
>    id | date                | name             | statusdate         
> ----: | :------------------ | :--------------- | :------------------
> 10001 | 2021-08-24 16:47:52 | Surname Lastname | 2021-09-02 10:01:13
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> id, `date`, `name`,`statusdate`
> FROM
> (SELECT `date`, `name`,`statusdate`,IF( `id` = @id,@rownum := @rownum +1,@rownum :=1) rn, @id := `id` as id
> FROM (select o.`id`,o.`date`, o.`name`,s.`statusdate`
> from orders o join status s on o.`id` = s.order_id
> where s.`status` = "shipped"
> order by o.`id` desc,s.`statusdate` DESC) t2 ,(SELECT @id := 0, @rownum:=0) t1) t2
> WHERE rn = 1
> ```

> ```
>    id | date                | name             | statusdate         
> ----: | :------------------ | :--------------- | :------------------
> 10001 | 2021-08-24 16:47:52 | Surname Lastname | 2021-09-02 10:01:13
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3163d029ad73d9038d605f6ed68bd6bc)*

Comment: Thank you for your help, i think i can understand your (first) query and what it does (copy & paste is not mine, i want to understand what i do).

But i have one problem, i guess i got it wrong to you:

If i'm using your query (2) from your fiddle example, he shows the order id 10001 in both tables for status "new", "pending" and "shipped", but the result should be that the order id only shows up in the table for status "shipped".

I have no idea if this is easy to change and you know what i mean?

Comment: no sorry o can't follow you, make a fiddle with more data and show with # at the start what it should look like

Comment: but try first to play around with the fiddle. it should be easy to add more information from the existing tables or even new joined ones

Comment: For example: I have 3 pages (index.php?status=new, ?status=pending and ?status=shipped) with tables showing the orders with the status from the URL. With your example on fiddle, the order id 10001 (latest/current status = shipped) listed in all 3 pages, instead of only on page ?status=shipped). So the query should only select the newest/current entry from the status table.

Comment: Maybe the easiest way is to save the current status of an order in addition to the STATUS table (=for the order history) in the ORDER table itself? Even if that is perhaps not the cleanest solution?

Comment: comments are very hard to read, make a fiddle, and try to show what you want with data. or make a new questions